# Sending username and password between domains securely

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, aes, rsa

We have a website www.domain1.com, and there the username/password pair for registered users are stored in domain1_db.

We will have another seperate domain (www.domain2.com) and if a user tries to login to domain2, the username/password will be sent to domain1, checked against domain1_db and if the user exists and password is true, a response will be sent to domain2 with username/password and a boolean (true or false)

For the security of the un+pw pair while sending it between domain1 and domain2. I have evaluated 3 options :

- AES encryption (key will be communicated at the beginning and the un+pw pair will be symmetrically encrypted)
- RSA encryption (domain1 and domain2 have their public/private key pairs. un+pw will be signed and encrypted)
- Self signed ssl certificates for domain1 and domain2

I want to evaluate these options :

- Is RSA an overkill for such a scenario? How is AES less secure than RSA in this scenario?
- What kind of vulnerabilities are there to consider with self signed certificates?

Comment: You said, "the username/password pair for registered users are stored in domain1_db."  I hope you mean salted hashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you're trying to build a system in which multiple web applications can use a single authentication system, you are almost certainly better off using an established protocol like [OAuth](http://oauth.net/). There are implementations for pretty much every language.

Secondly, the only way to evaluate a security solution is to understand the context. There are solutions that are always bad (e.g. homegrown encryption algorithms), but there are no solutions that are always sufficient - an attacker with limitless resources can break most solutions.

Your first question is answered [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34983/symmetric-key-cryptography-vs-public-key-cryptography): if both websites belong to you, and will always belong to you, you can use symmetric crypto.

The second question is answered [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8110/what-are-the-risks-of-self-signing-a-certificate-for-ssl): an attacker who can persuade domain2 to accept a different computer as domain1 can trick domain2 into sending all the data to this server; this is a classic ["man-in-the-middle" attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Answer (score 1):

The weakness is in the keys and key exchange. I'll assume you will use strong keys for each of your choices.

If you control both machines and can use out-of-band key exchange (thumb drive over sneaker-net, etc.) then symmetric crypto (e.g. AES) will be faster and much more secure.

Asymmetric crypto (e.g. RSA) are weak during the Diffie-Hellman key exchange, which is why SSL is no longer secure and everyone has moved to TLS. However, asymmetric crypto solves the "I don't control both machines" problem, so we tolerate it being slightly less secure.

Self signed certs is the worst option because if you don't control both machines it will just fail or throw warnings. If you control both machines just use AES.

P.S. With SSL and TLS, RSA is only used briefly. Just long enough to exchange a symmetric key. After that it's all symmetric crypto anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTPS when sending the username/password between the sites would suffice for securing the transport of the credentials.

The real question here is why do you need to send the password back to domain2 in the first place? If domain2 trusts domain1 to verify the username and password, all it needs is the result (valid user or not) and maybe some extra information like user's name and email address or something. It should not need the user's password.

Also, domain1 should not be storing the password in a way in which it can be retrieved. Passwords need to be stored in a [salted hashed](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/) form.

A better approach would be to use an external identity provider that provides Single Sign On (SSO) for both sites, so you don't have to bother with storing passwords at all.